# Using GitHub access token publicly

Tags: github, access-token

I need to use GitHub access token publicly but somehow restrict it to my site.

The use case:
I have created a portfolio web page that pulls some information from Github. Some of the information I need require an access token. I can generate an access token and use it with the fetch requests to get the info, however, it's not secure to do it this way as the access token would be visible to public users. So I'm wondering if there is a way to restrict the use of the access token to the domain, IP address, or maybe there is another way to authenticate requests without an access token?

Edit: It seems like GitHub allows users to create a PAT with no access and users would still be able to authenticate. Though a slightly different question, would publishing such a token be a problem?

Answer (score 3):

The best way to do this is to have some sort of backend server that stores your access token and uses it to present the data.  That way, your token will remain secure and you won't need to expose it to others, but you can still fetch the data (and cache it) to present to the user.

There's no way to do this securely with a static website.

Publishing any sort of token, even one with no privileges, still exposes the token to be stolen.  That would count against your rate limit, and if it's used to make expensive requests that cause a DoS, then your account would be responsible for it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer bk2204. Unfortunately, the site is purely frontend. Someone did suggest creating a token with only 'public_repo' access and publishing it. Though seems like a good answer, the user seems to have deleted it. I edited my question to include a slightly different question.

Comment: I've explained why that's insecure.  As mentioned, if your site is frontend only, then there's no secure way to do what you want.  Any type of secret published as part of such a site will be a security problem.

Comment: Worth mentioning: a token with _zero permissions_ will still be permitted to read all _public repositories_ and _open issues_, _write comments_, _fork projects_, etc., and that can open to spammy behavior anonymously by anyone >,<"